# File began saving to the wrong location. Xamarin UITest

Tags: xamarin, fileinfo, xamarin.uitest

In the middle of developing some new tests my scripts began to fail when copying snapshots. I've been using

```
FileInfo info =App.Screenshot("title");
info.MoveTo("New\Location");
```

which seems to be the suggested way of handling local screenshots. I was having no problems till all of sudden it began throwing `FileNotFound` errors. After doing some research I figured out it had started saving the file to `Windows\System32` instead of the active directory. I ended up restarting the entire system and now its saving to the active directory again.

I'm not sure why that made it unable to find the file. I didn't get a chance to debug and see if the info object had the location it was supposed to be in and it just never saved there or if there was a permission problem with accessing `Windows\System32`. I'm more concerned though with why it starting saving to the wrong location in the first place and why a reboot fixed it.

Why would a method that's supposed to save to the active director stop saving there?

Comment: Your last paragraph cuts off and you didn't actually ask a question.

Comment: @Andrew Crap my bad. Missed some when I copied from another forum.